# AutoUpdater Code

Tags: c#, auto-update

```
        private void UpdatesButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebRequest wr = WebRequest.Create(new Uri("http://Test.com/Updater/Test.txt"));
        WebResponse ws = wr.GetResponse();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ws.GetResponseStream());

        string currentversion = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
        string newversion = sr.ReadToEnd();

        if (currentversion.Contains(newversion))
        {
            this.ShowMessageAsync("Updater", "Your client is up to date !");
        }
        else
        {
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Completed);
            webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://Test.com/Updater/Test.exe"), @"TestUpdated.exe");
        }
    }

    private void Completed(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        File.Replace("Test.exe", "TestUpdated.exe", "TestOld.exe");
        Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
    }
```

this is my code and when i click the button to update the program is crashed.
can some help me to fix this ?

or give me another code that working..

Comment: If `Test.exe` is running, then you *cannot* replace it (you are probably getting an exception from the `File.Replace` (you should look at that and include that information in your question).

Comment: @crashmstr yes i got an exception , can you help me with that code ?

Comment: The information in the exception (the type, the string, and perhaps any inner exception) is a *very* important clue as to what is wrong. Any question with code that throws an exception should include that information.

Comment: As a note to how to "fix" this: you need to have a second program that can to the replacement. Call it and exit, it waits for `Test.exe` to close then replaces the old `Test.exe`, then launches `Test.exe` and exits.

Comment: @crashmstr great fix ! :) i will try it now !